# Using which command in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on porting a CoffeeScript to native NodeJS but I'm coming across a few bumps, It's basically "signing" after injecting files.

The error I'm getting is: ***ReferenceError: which is not defined***

Here's my Node code:

```
ossl = which('osslsigncode');

if (!ossl) {
    log('Warning: osslsigncode not found, code-signing disabled');
}
```

Here's the original CoffeeScript code:

```
ossl = which 'osslsigncode'
if !ossl
  log 'Warning: osslsigncode not found, code-signing disabled'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *presume* the application you were using this with was using the [which](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) package to verify whether a binary exists.

You'd need to install this and call it using the Node syntax.

Comment: Hmm, after doing this; it now responds with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'colon' of undefined` from ` at getPathInfo (node_modules\which\which.js:20:19)`

Comment: @Curtis try `which.sync('...');`